# Ubuntu 17.04 Virtualbox cant ping website

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, ping

I am trying to ping a certain website from my Ubuntu VM, but I dont seem to be having any luck. When i ping the website (www.anu.edu.au), nothing shows up at all. After cancelling the command it shows 100% packet loss.

Can someone help me with this? I am trying to get ICMP response 'Host unreachable' from www.anu.edu.au but I dont even get anything.

I have set my connection to 'Bridged Adapter', Promiscuous Mode deny. I can surf the web using FireFox browser, and can even access the site that I try to ping to. I can ping Google OpenDNS 8.8.8.8 and get responses. I can ping facebook.com or runescape.com. I can ping my host (Windows 8.1). My host can ping www.anu.edu.au and at least receive "Request timed out.", but my Ubuntu VM shows nothing at all.

Comment: There is no real difference between your Windows system and your Ubuntu VM pinging anu.edu.au other than the way they are displaying their pings to the remote host. Windows will show each "Request timed out" while Linux doesn't display that when pings aren't being returned. In both cases they are getting 100% packet loss since anu.edu.au is blocking ping requests.

Comment: I have both Windows and Linux systems right now and the behave the same way. It's just their different ways of displaying pings in real time. There is nothing wrong with your Ubuntu VM network settings.